# Why do both "and" and "or" exist?

Tags: logic, definition, conventions

Why do both "and" and "or" exist?

"and" is just a change in the argument of "or", and vice versa.

> a || b = !(!a && !b)
>
> a && b = !(!a || !b)

So why do we have both of them? Do they both exist simply for convenience in defining other more complicated logical structures?

Another aspect of this question I am interested in is whether one of these considered more fundamental than the other when creating computers.

I suppose another way of asking it is, why do we not have no "or's" or no "and's"? (I think)

Comment: ... So we don't have to build either from their more-complicated equivalents? Why do we have *any* conveniences? Why not just code in octal?

Comment: For the first, for the sake of readability and brevity. Code would be atrocious if you have to apply Moore's law (or who's every law that is) every time you wanted to read/write a conditional.

Comment: In a || b, you don't need to know the value of b if a is true.
In a && b you don't need to know the value of b if a is false.

Comment: You can build a computer completely out of NAND gates, but we prefer to build abstractions so that the system diagram remains readable at each level.

Comment: Like the other commenters already said, readability and brevity. It's the same reason most programmers today don't code in a assembly language anymore ( unless they want to be really close to the metal ). We couldn't produce as much software as we do today, if we didn't make the langauges more readable, like simplyfing often repeated code.